# This weird piece of code I always see in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm not Javascript expert, but the old Javascript I know is just a bunch of simple functions and variables like this:

```
function doSomething(){
    var data = "test";
    return data;
}
```

But lately I'm seeing some Javascript code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#about").hide();
                    $(".tababout").collapser({
                        target: '#about',
                        effect: 'slide',
                        changeText: false,
                    });
        });
```

What the hell is this? What is it called? Is it easier and supported by all browsers? I need more informations about this please.

Comment: As JohnD said, this is most likely the library *jQuery*. However, it is of course still JavaScript, so if this syntax looks strange to you, you should dig deeper into JavaScript. [A very comprehensive guide is provided by MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking at is [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). It's an external library but it supports [most](http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_Compatibility) (if not all) browsers. You need to download it and include it with your project if you were to use it though, see [Downloading jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery) for that.

Comment: is it supported by all browsers?

Comment: They claim IE 6.0+, FF 2.0+, Safari 3.0+, Opera 9.0+, Chrome. See also http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_Compatibility

Comment: Browsers don't support jQuery. Browsers support specifications (to varying degree) and jQuery supports certain browsers.

Comment: Also, that's different from a function declaration! Of course, functions are declared in the standard way [or as `myFunc = function() { ... }` to look like more pro :P]; that is a function call to `$(document).ready()` passing a callback function to be registered for execution upon page load [in short words, all the code enclosed between the first and last row is executed when the page loads].

Answer (score 1):

It's just plain old javascript:

```
var $ = function(sel) {
    return new init(sel);
};

function init(sel) {
    if (sel.nodeName) {
        this[0] = sel;
        this.length = 1;
    } else {
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll(sel);
        for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
            this[i] = elems[i];
        }
        this.length = elems.length;
    }
    return this;
};
init.prototype.ready = function(fn) {
    _ready(fn);
    return this;
};
function _ready(fn) {
    if (!document.body) {
        setTimeout(function(){_ready(fn);}, 0);
    } else {
        fn();
    }
}
init.prototype.hide = function() {
    this.each(function() {
        this.style.display = 'none';
    });
    return this;
};
init.prototype.show = function() {
    this.each(function() {
        this.style.display = 'block';
    });
    return this;
};
init.prototype.each = function(fn) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        fn.call(this[i], i, this[i]);
    }
    return this;
};
```

---

```
$("#about").hide().each(function(i,el) {

    setTimeout( function(){$(el).show()}, 2000 );

});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/JGWUs/3/